# how can I use turtle-sets with turtles-on keyword in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

to start with the **example**:

```
to move-cars
  ask turtles with [ shape = "car"] [
    ifelse not can-move? 1
      [ die! ]
      [ ifelse [ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 1 = red [] [ifelse any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1 [] [ fd 1 ] ]]
  ]
```

This is my procedure to move-cars. Cars can only move when there is no red patch ahead or no cars ahead.

Problem I'm having is caused by **turtles-on** in the second part of ifelse because it checks all turtles. I do have several car breeds and also other turtle agents I do not want to check. I only want to check if **turtles-on for specific turtle set**. In this case

```
turtles with [ shape = "car" ]
```

To sum it up I want to ask: (in words) **are any turtles with car shape on one patch ahead?**

I tried this but to no avail:

```
[ ifelse [ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 1 = red [] [ifelse any? turtles-on turtles with [shape = "car"] patch-ahead 1 [] [ fd 1 ] ]]
```

At the end of the day, I solved the issue but the solution is ugly and redundant. I checked if any specific breed is one patch ahead because I know that I can use **breed-on**. Here it is:

```
[ ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = red [] [ ifelse any? carsSN-on patch-ahead 1 or any? carsSE-on patch-ahead 1 or any? carsEN-on patch-ahead 1 or any? carsWS-on patch-ahead 1 or any? carsNS-on patch-ahead 1 or any? carsNE-on patch-ahead 1 or any? carsES-on patch-ahead 1[  ] [ fd 1 ] ] ]
```

Can you suggest better way to use turtles-on with specific agent set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach with `with [ shape = "car" ]` has some syntax issues, otherwise it should be a viable approach. You can't use `turtles-on turtles`, since `turtles-on` only really makes sense in a patch context. In that same vein, you would need to indicate that you're wanting the `turtles-on` *of* a specific patch (patch-ahead 1) using the primitive `of`. A variation of your approach is:

```
  ask cars [
    if patch-ahead 1 != nobody [
      if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 != red and [ count turtles-here with [ shape = "car"] ] of patch-ahead 1 = 0 [
        fd 1
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Also, is there any specific reason you are using `ifelse` in every case instead of just using != in an if statement (as I did here)?

As a side note, personally I'd recommend against using different breeds for your cars travelling in different directions. I prefer having a single breed that can all follow the same rules. It is cleaner, and you can still differentiate within the breed (for example, a `turtles-own` for starting direction). It would also eliminate the issue you're having here by only having one breed to deal with. That said, I'm sure that in some cases the multiple breeds would be better, and if it makes sense for your model then great!

Comment: ```[count turtles-here with [ shape = "car" ]] of patch ahead 1 = 0``` works well... thanks for your help